# Invalidating the session after session timeout - Is it necessary?

Tags: spring, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, session-timeout

In my AJAX Spring application, have added code in web.xml for a session timeout of 10 minutes.
If the user tries to access the page after this interval, he is getting redirected to the session time out page correctly.

But if the user clicks the back button, the url with the same session id actually returns values instead of displaying the "timeout" page again. This happens only in IE9 . In all others, this is working correctly.

Any pointers?
Should I manually invalidate the session after a request from an invalidated page? If I manually invalidate the session in my controller, for such a request, it seems to work perfectly even in IE9. Can anyone explain why this occurs?

Comment: Sounds like a page caching issue. I would check whether a request is actually sent to the server when the back-button is pressed.

Comment: @Luke Taylor Yes the request is being sent to the server . I verified using firebug and server logs